# How to put a @Model string inside a html string

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I put a @Model string inside a html string?

```
<img src="/img/users/@Model.Short.jpg.ashx?width=80&height=80" width="80" height="80" alt="" />
```

The @Model.Short is the string I need to have as a part if the img src. The problem I have is that it gives an error as it thinks .jpg.ashx is a part of the @Model.Short and doesn't know that it should print that as it is.

The only thing I can think of now is to do this in JavaScript, but it would make more sense to have it "hardcoded" in the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parentheses:

```
<img src="/img/users/@(Model.Short).jpg.ashx?width=80&height=80" ... />
```